# Find the speed of the man

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, relative-motion

> A man runs at constant speed to catch a bus. At the instant the man is $40$ metres from the bus, it begins to accelerate uniformly from rest away from him. The man just catches the bus $20$ seconds later.
>
> (i) Find the constant speed of the man.
>
> (ii) If the constant speed of the man had instead been $3$ m/s, show that the closest he gets to the bus is $17.5$ metres.

I can't even solve for the first part. I feel there is some more information required. I draw a velocity/time graph. Let the distance that the bus moves be $d$. The man's velocity is therefore: $v_{man}=\frac{40+d}{20}$. The bus is accelerating at $f$ m/s for the same time of $20$ s. I get the expression: $d=200f$. I didn't know where to go from there. I combined the expressions to get $v_{man}=2+20f$. Now I have two expressions for $v_{man}$ but I don't know either $d$ or $f$.

I gave part (ii) also just in case it was required to solve for (i) but I don't think it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if it means $v_{\text{man}} = v_{\text{bus}}$ when he just catches the bus.  This gives you another equation, so it should be solvable.

Answer (score 1):

The part you are missing is the acceleration of the bus.  You can easily see this matters by looking at absurd cases.

If the acceleration is just above 0, the bus won't have moved far by the time the man catches up to it.  In the limiting case, the man's speed would only need to be (40 m)/(20 s) = 2 m/s.

If the bus accelerates quickly, then it should be obvious that the man can never catch it.  Whatever the speed the man is running at, it will take him a finite time just to get to where the bus started.  Clearly if the bus accelerates to the man's speed in that time, there is a gap between the man and the bus when the speed of the two match.  After that, the gap only widens.

### Added

Your answer assumes that "just catches" the bus implies that the man gets to the bus right at the time it would accelerate past his speed.  It's not clear to me that's what's meant, but if so, you do have the additional degree of freedom required to solve this problem.  In that case, you don't need to know the acceleration of the bus up front, and can infer it from the additional constraint.

You might want to check that this is really what is intended to be understood from "just catches".

Answer (score 0):

Ah , the final velocity of the bus is the same as that for the man "just catches the bus". Now I have enough information. $v_{man}=4$ m/s

And the second part works out nicely too.